# python entry_point no module name __main__

Tags: python, pip, python-packaging, entry-point

I have been trying to set a new entry point for my project instead of cli, I wanted to launch main(). I have tried several variations in setup.py and can't seem to get main to import properly when it is installed with pip3

Here is the entry point code in setup.py (Note the old # code worked before with click for CLI)

```
entry_points={
    'console_scripts': [
        'shenko = shenko.__main__:main',
    ],
},
# This was the old entry point to run shenko as command line
#entry_points={
#    'console_scripts': [
#        'shenko=shenko.cli:main',
#    ],
#},
```

Here is the source code;
[github code, look in setup.py](https://github.com/shenko/shenko)

Here is the last Traceback I got;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/shenko/.local/bin/shenko", line 5, in <module>
from shenko.__main__ import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'shenko.__main__'
```

In setup.py I have tried the following code;

```
'shenko = shenko.__main__:main'
'shenko = shenko:main'
'shenko = shenko.main:main'
```

Neither worked. Any suggestions are welcome
Thank you for your time, it is most apreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  If possible, please modify your question so that it is self contained, including all of the necessary code directly instead of via a Github link.  Questions tend to break over time if they utilize external references.  You may want to refer to [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 5):

You don't have anything named `__main__`. It's [neither a module `__main__.py`](https://github.com/shenko/shenko/tree/db1208a6ef94ee37342d1ede7ad11a8f813df506/shenko) [nor a function in `__init__.py`](https://github.com/shenko/shenko/blob/db1208a6ef94ee37342d1ede7ad11a8f813df506/shenko/__init__.py). Instead you have [a module `cli.py`](https://github.com/shenko/shenko/blob/db1208a6ef94ee37342d1ede7ad11a8f813df506/shenko/cli.py) with a [function `main()`](https://github.com/shenko/shenko/blob/db1208a6ef94ee37342d1ede7ad11a8f813df506/shenko/cli.py#L8). So try this:

```
entry_points={
    'console_scripts': [
        'shenko = shenko.cli:main',
    ],
},
```

Comment: I don't want to use 'click' I just wanted to run main directly from 'shenko.py' so I need to add main to __init__.py maybe? eitherway I think you just put me back on track, thanx for the help @phd.

Comment: @DannyDowshenko Then it's `'shenko = shenko.shenko:main',`

Comment: re-tried you suggestion if failed with same error, then I thought it was my __init__ file so I modified that and got a slightly different error;

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shenko/.local/bin/shenko", line 5, in <module>
    from shenko.shenko import main
  File "/home/shenko/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/shenko/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from shenko import main
ImportError: cannot import name 'main' from partially initialized module 'shenko' (most likely due to a circular import) (/home/shenko/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/shenko/__init__.py)

Comment: line 39 of my setup.py "packages=find_packages(include=['shenko',"   is that what is making it a circular import???? I will try and remove this to see what happens.

Comment: I give up, here was the last traceback                                                                                                              Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shenko/.local/bin/shenko", line 5, in <module>
    from shenko.shenko import main
  File "/home/shenko/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/shenko/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from shenko import main
ImportError: cannot import name 'main' from partially initialized module 'shenko' (most likely due to a circular import) (/home/shenko/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/shenko/__init__.py)

Answer (score -1):

Confirmed to be working with @phd's answer

'shenko = shenko.shenko:main'

shenko folder
calls shenko.py
calls main()

The issues I was having were unrelated.

Thank you for your help phd, I owe you a beer!

Comment: next best thing you can do would be to accept phd's answer, that way this post will be protected from deletion, and they get some points for their effort =)